# I want to replace dataset api with datstream api

Tags: dataset, apache-flink

My flink version is 1.13.

```
dataSet.first(limit).print();
```

How to replace it with datastream api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't use Flink SQL, then you could write your own `limit` operator, something like (warning, untested!):

```java
public class LimitFilter<T> extends RichFilterFunction<T> {

    private int _limit;
    
    private transient int _remainingRecords;
    
    public LimitFilter(int limit) {
        _limit = limit;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void open(Configuration parameters) throws Exception {
        super.open(parameters);
        
        // Calc number of records to return from this subtask
        int mySubtask = getRuntimeContext().getIndexOfThisSubtask();
        int remainingItems = _limit;
        int parallelism = getRuntimeContext().getNumberOfParallelSubtasks();
        for (int i = 0; i < parallelism; i++) {
            int remainingGroups = parallelism - i;
            int itemsInGroup = remainingItems / remainingGroups;
            if (i == mySubtask) {
                _remainingRecords = itemsInGroup;
                break;
            }
            
            remainingItems -= itemsInGroup;
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean filter(T value) throws Exception {
        if (_remainingRecords <= 0) {
            return false;
        }
        
        _remainingRecords--;
        return true;
    }

}
```

This will only work well with parallelism > 1 if you have some reasonably random distribution of data between the operators, e.g. use a `rebalance()` right before the `.filter(new LimitFilter(limit))` operator.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of DataSet the data is finite while for a DataStream the number of elements can be unbounded. I think you know it already so the notion of `.first(n)` elements is not the same when you reading data arriving continuously sometimes out of order.

Comment: Flink's DataStream API can also be executed in BATCH execution mode. From the original question I'm not sure if the goal is to move from a Batch to a Streaming application (and therefore moving from DataSet to DataStream) or if the user wants to migrate from API (and therefore migrate from DataSet to DataStream)

Comment: Thanks. I just migrated the api from dataset to datstream and still executing in batch mode.